# adding a grub2 menuentry to a local disk grub to enable booting from a pxe server

Tags: grub2, netboot

Here is my scenario:

- Have a pxeserver on a private network.
- have pc systems with no graphics cards, but all have serial port.
- all boot from grub2 to local disk.

What I want to do is to add an entry, in the local grub config, to send the booted grub instance to the pxserver to start a new install.

I can find all kinds of info how to setup on the pxserver, but come up empty on the incantation to have the local grub2.cfg access the network after booting from disk.

Is it possible?

The normal process, when there is a graphics card on the pc, to go into bios and select booting from the network.

EDIT: to narrow the responses, is there a way to insmod or chainload networking from a disk based grub.cfg?

Comment: You try a network boot over grub for os install?

Comment: yes, being able to pxeboot, using the bios menu is fine.

Comment: OK you get it Work now?

Comment: but none of the systems have pxeboot enabled in bios, as they are in a steady state booting from the disk. some are headless, and the only way to be able to select pxeboot is to physically install a graphics card to get to the bios menu.

I am trying to avoid pulling the system apart to add a graphics card just to use the pxeboot from the card, and just be able to netboot from the menu presented over the serial port, from the grub2 menu on the local disk.

Comment: It's a Laptop or Tower? BIOS Version? Can you flash the BIOS?

Comment: Maybe you can reset all BIOS settings without a Card. On Standard settings normal Network Boot ist on, If presentet in bios

Comment: Try over the Mainboard or maybe some Keyboard combo

Comment: What you wanna do with this Machines?

Comment: Why you need To-Do an Install over Network? There is a better solution for that.

Comment: You got only a serial Port or Ethernet too?

Comment: all systems have serial and ethernet.  biosi are all last available.  some machines are old enough  to be in high school.

Comment: With Disk you mean Harddisk ?

Comment: Is it possible to Boot over USB?

Comment: My Last question now, time to sleep.Will you Boot an runing Image or will you do a New Install over the Network? How will you manage the config over Install without Screen?